# How to select the item names for multiple instances of item id in another table

Tags: sql

The `Menu` table has the following attributes:

```
MEAL_ID
MEAL_NAME
MEAL_TYPE
ITEM1_ID
ITEM2_ID
ITEM3_ID
ITEM4_ID
ITEM5_ID
COST
ACTIVE_INDICATOR
```

The `item` table had the following attributes:

```
ITEM_ID
ITEM_NAME 
ACTIVE_INDICATOR
```

I am trying to print the name of each item for each instance of the `item_id` in the `menu` table;

`select a.MEAL_ID, a.MEAL_NAME, a.MEAL_TYPE, b.ITEM_NAME, b.ITEM_NAME from mdw_meals_menu a, mdw_item_menu b where a.ITEM1_ID = b.ITEM_ID and a.Item2_ID= b.ITEM_ID and a.item3_id= b.ITEM_ID and a.item4_id =  b.ITEM_ID and a.item5_ID= b.ITEM_ID;`

This is the code that i used, but it is not returning any values. Please help

Comment: Your menu table has ITEM1_ID ITEM2_ID ITEM3_ID ITEM4_ID ITEM5_ID?  You almost certainly haven't structured your tables correctly.  Google "normalize database"

Comment: How can i display the names for each item ID using a subqyery for each item id in the menu table?

Comment: Do you want 1 row with all the items, or 5 different rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider moving the Items into a different table to normalize your database.  Consider having a Meal_Items table with a Meal_Id and an Item_Id -- that way you could have a 1-n number of items associated with each meal.

However, assuming you want 1 row with all the item names, then you need to `JOIN` your menu table to the item table for each item:

```
SELECT m.Meal_Id, a.Meal_Name, a.Meal_Type, 
    i1.Item_Name Item_Name_1,
    i2.Item_Name Item_Name_2,
    i3.Item_Name Item_Name_3,
    i4.Item_Name Item_Name_4,
    i5.Item_Name Item_Name_5
FROM mdw_meals_menu m
   LEFT JOIN mdw_item_menu i1 ON m.Item1_Id = i1.Item_Id
   LEFT JOIN mdw_item_menu i2 ON m.Item2_Id = i2.Item_Id
   LEFT JOIN mdw_item_menu i3 ON m.Item3_Id = i3.Item_Id
   LEFT JOIN mdw_item_menu i4 ON m.Item4_Id = i4.Item_Id
   LEFT JOIN mdw_item_menu i5 ON m.Item5_Id = i5.Item_Id
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` in case the Item did not exist, but you may be able to just use an `INNER JOIN` depending on your data.

Comment: isnt that what it is, each menu has 5 items, and the item id's are stored in the row, the item id's point to the item table which has all details about the items.

Comment: @debal -- glad you got it working.  In a normalized database, you'd have a menu table, an item table, and then a menu_item table.  That way you could store 0 items, 1 item or any number of items associated to a menu and not restrict yourself to just 5.  However, if this works for your needs, then no need to change.  Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT  a.MEAL_ID ,
        a.MEAL_NAME ,
        a.MEAL_TYPE ,
        b.ITEM_NAME 
FROM    mdw_meals_menu a ,
        mdw_item_menu b
WHERE   b.ITEM_ID IN ( SELECT   ITEM1_ID
                   FROM     mdw_meals_menu
                   UNION
                   SELECT   ITEM2_ID
                   FROM     mdw_meals_menu
                   UNION
                   SELECT   ITEM3_ID
                   FROM     mdw_meals_menu
                   UNION
                   SELECT   ITEM4_ID
                   FROM     mdw_meals_menu
                   UNION
                   SELECT   ITEM5_ID
                   FROM     mdw_meals_menu )
```

Answer (score 0):

I still think you should consider re-designing your table structure, but...

```
SELECT m.meal_id, m.meal_name, m.meal_type, i1.item_name AS item_name1, i2.item_name AS item_name2
FROM mdw_meals_menu AS m
INNER JOIN mdw_item_menu AS i1 ON i1.item_id=m.item1_id 
INNER JOIN mdw_item_menu AS i2 ON i2.item_id=m.item2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put these all on one row by doing five joins:

```
select mm.MEAL_ID, mm.MEAL_NAME, mm.MEAL_TYPE, m1.ITEM_NAME, m2.ITEM_NAME,
       m3.item_name, m4.item_name, m5.item_name
from mdw_meals_menu mm left join
     mdw_item_menu mi1
     on mm.ITEM1_ID = mi1.ITEM_ID left join
     mdw_item_menu mi2
     on mm.ITEM2_ID = mi2.ITEM_ID left join
     mdw_item_menu mi3
     on mm.ITEM3_ID = mi3.ITEM_ID left join
     mdw_item_menu mi4
     on mm.ITEM4_ID = mi4.ITEM_ID left join
     mdw_item_menu mi5
     on mm.ITEM5_ID = mi5.ITEM_ID
```

This query fixes both your join syntax and your use of aliases (aliases should be abbreviations for the table to enhance readability).  The use of `left join` instead of `inner join` is to be sure that no rows drop out.  This is standard syntax and should work in any database.